# Create bufio interface from string in golang

Tags: go

I want to write unit tests in golang for a struct which accepts an io.Reader in the constructor. Usually the io.Reader interface is coming from a TCP connection.

Now I want to use a predefined string and use this as input to the io.Reader interface.

Something like:

```
s := "this is my input"
b := io.NewReader(s)
t := NewTestStruct(b)
t.doSomething()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`strings.Reader`](https://godoc.org/strings#Reader) implements the [`io.Reader`](https://godoc.org/io#Reader) interface. You can construct a new instance of it using [`strings.NewReader`](https://godoc.org/strings#NewReader):

```
s := "this is my input"
b := strings.NewReader(s)
t := NewTestStruct(b)
t.doSomething()
```

Answer (score 5):

This should be correct way:

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(strings.NewReader("some string"))
```